# Why pandas read_excel not reading correctly xls file?

Tags: python, pandas

I am just trying to open the xls file with pandas with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

frame = pd.read_excel('15_6z_12N_11.xlsx', skiprows=3)
df = pd.DataFrame(frame)
#pd.read_excel('your_excel.xlsx', , skip_blank_lines=False)

print(df)
```

**and return is**

```
     Unnamed: 0  185  ...  Unnamed: 254  Unnamed: 255
0           NaN  NaN  ...           NaN           NaN
1           NaN  NaN  ...           NaN           NaN
2           NaN  NaN  ...           NaN           NaN
3           NaN  NaN  ...           NaN           NaN
4           NaN  NaN  ...           NaN           NaN
..          ...  ...  ...           ...           ...
993         NaN  NaN  ...           NaN           NaN
994         NaN  NaN  ...           NaN           NaN
995         NaN  NaN  ...           NaN           NaN
996         NaN  NaN  ...           NaN           NaN
997         NaN  NaN  ...           NaN           NaN
```

**when my file contains following data:**
[Data from xls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsHEK.png)

Any idea why output is incorrect?
Thanks

[Here is xls file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AVYcwZnUn-YOwSbrJ3H3b4zZ_0UnbUNq/view?usp=sharing)
But sorry it is in russian language

Comment: Is possible share file? Because hard test from picture.

Comment: @jezrael updated a link to download.

Comment: @S3DEV the same output

Comment: @jezrael Can you give an example or explain with details?

Comment: @SergeBallesta no, threre is only one sheet

Comment: @SergeBallesta ohh I see now, realised that the sheet_name is PRINT(while default is List), so i have to specify name. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create `DataFrame` with specify sheetname, omit first 3 rows and next 3 rows convert to `MultiIndex`:

```
df = pd.read_excel('15_6z_12N_11.xls', sheet_name='PRINT', skiprows=3, header=[0,1,2])
```

Ant then is possible flatten `Multiindex` with remove `Unnamed` strings:

```
df.columns = ['_'.join(y for y in x if not 'Unnamed' in y) for x in df.columns.tolist()]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df = pd.read_excel('15_6z_12N_11.xlsx', header=[0,1,2]) #Read file, use 3 rows as header
```